# Would it be feasible to create a GSM, 3G, LTE, or 5G NR ham radio network?

Tags: united-states, phone

Would it be feasible to create a cellular network compatible with standard unlocked phones using amateur frequencies and following amateur regulations?

Comment: *Possible* duplicate of https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/10554/is-there-a-practical-way-for-hams-to-participate-in-cellular-related-technology or https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/814/can-an-amateur-use-cellular-technologies-with-sdr. But this asks a slightly different and more specific question. (The discussion on https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/where-to-apply-for-an-amateur-lte-radio-license-in-the-usa may be somewhat relevant as well.)

Comment: I'd consider it a duplicate of the first question that you mention, @natevw-AF7TB, which was a very nice question. Yes. It's possible. It has been done.

Comment: I don't know how, there would be so many hurdles. More possible is a universal HAM network dongle to plug into a phone? Maybe existing 2300+ MHz Digital equipment... ?